# Django Rest Framework - Add fields to JSON

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

Now I return a JSON file with the model fields and their values. I want to add some extra fields to the JSON that are not present in the model (I want to add a new field that specifies if an user can modify or not the diagnostic based on the permissions of the view). How I can do this?

models.py

```
class Diagnostic(models.Model):
    Center = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Author = models.TextField(blank=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    Date = models.DateField(null = True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class DiagnosticViewSet(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    model = Diagnostic
    permission_classes = [GroupPermission]
```

serializers.py

```
class DiagnosticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Diagnostic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your views

```
 def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(Classname, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    try:
        response.data['permission'] = 'give your permission'
    except:
        pass
    return response
```

Comment: I've tried the code and works, but not exactly. If I do a GET in localhost/diagnostics works perfectly, but if I do a GET in localhost/diagnostics/1 the permission field in the JSON doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

You add them to the serializer.

```
class DiagnosticSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    auth_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_auth_status')
    class Meta:
        model = Diagnostic

    def get_auth_status(self, obj):
        if obj.has_auth():
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use following code for the url localhost/diagnostics/1

```
 from rest_framework.response import Response

 def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object)
    data = serializer.data
    data['permission'] = 'give your permission'
    return Response(data)
```